# Example of a surjective local homeomorphism that is not a covering?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, examples-counterexamples, covering-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be connected, locally path connected, and Hausdorff topological spaces. Can someone give me an example of a surjective local homeomorphism that is not a covering?

I don't think this is the same question as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447168/local-homeomorphisms-which-are-not-covering-map)? There's different conditions?

Comment: It's not quite the same question, but it has the same answer :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Restrict the usual covering projection from the real line to the circle(that is $x$ goes to $e^{2\pi ix}$) on the positive side of the line.

$p:R_+\rightarrow S^1$ defined as
$p(x)=(\cos2\pi x,\sin2\pi x)$

This is a local homeomorphism but not covering projection. As the point $(1,0)$ on the circle is not evenly covered by the projection map.

Comment: What makes you say $(0,1)$ is not evenly covered?

Comment: sorry it would be (1,0).It is a typo.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more detail?

Comment: Why got this answer downvoted?

Comment: @user141494 inverse of any open set  U containing the point (1,0) will look line open intervals $V_a$containing the integer points on $R^+$ ,as all the integers on $R^+$ maps to (1,0) under the projection map. By the definition of covering maps these $V_a$ should be homeomorphic to U when you restricts to $V_a$'s.But in this case open interval say $V_0$ containing 0 is not homeomorphic to U, as  restriction map from  $V_0$ to U is not surjective. So the above mentioned map is not a covering map.

Comment: I think you need to take $R_+$ without $0$, otherwise $p$ is not an open map.

Comment: @StefanHamcke  yes, you are right....Thanks

Comment: @RipanSaha I don't understand why (1,0) is not evenly covered by the exponential. Can you help me?