# Discrete fibers vs local homeomorphism vs covering map

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

I was wondering about the difference between the following possible conditions on a given continuous map $f : X \rightarrow Y$ between topological spaces:

1. $f$ has discrete fibers
2. $f$ is a local homeomorphism
3. $f$ is a covering map.

As far as I know, 3 implies 1 and 2; however, I am wondering if there are any further implications between these three properties, or if there are counter-examples between them.

Would anyone have any suggestions as to where I can find proofs or counter-examples of these?

Comment: 3 implies 2 and 2 implies 1. Neither implication is reversible.

Comment: To see that 1 does not implies 2, consider the map $f\colon \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ given by $f(z) = z^2$.

Comment: here you get examples of 2 not implying 3: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447168/local-homeomorphisms-which-are-not-covering-map

Comment: Thanks very much for your help!